# Subscript overlap issue with \mathclap

Tags: math-mode, spacing, subscripts, mathtools

I wanted to use `\mathclap` (from `mathtools`) to make more compact the appearance of

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) \]
\end{document}
```

[image: nomathclap]

I decided to use `\mathclap`, so I replaced the above code with

```
\[ \lim_{\mathclap{(x,y)\to (0,0)}} f(x,y) \]
```

[image: mathclap]

but as can be seen in the resulting picture, `f(x,y)` dips a bit too low and brushes against the subscript of the limit. Are there any good ways to make the appearance compact without getting the overlapping of `f(x,y)` with the subscript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can lower that subscript by a little by adding an invisible rule via `\mystrut`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule{0pt}{1.6ex}}   %% <-- adjust this
\begin{document}
  \[ \lim_{\mathclap{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)\mystrut}}  f(x,y) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oops, I must have edited my example after you started writing your solution. but the solution still works, of course :)